# Convert string to time JavaScript (h:m)

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, date, time

My friend and I are doing a school project; the task is to make a room-reservation-site.
This is our first year trying JavaScript, and we want a string to be formatted into time (h:m).
The user of our room-reservation-site can choose what time of the day he/she wants the room, and the output is: H:m (24hour-clock:minutes).
For example 12:15.

Therefor my question is:
Is there possible to convert this string (h:m) into time, and easily check if the user typed more than 30minutes of booking-time? So we can for example say:

```
 if(start_of_reservation < start_of_reservation(+30minutes)){ 
   alert("You need to book a room atleast 30minutes"); }

 else if(start_of_reservation > start_of_reservation(+6hours)){ 
   alert("You can't book a room longer than 6 hours"); }

 else {
 // moving on..
 }
```

Comment: There are many javascript date libs: * http://momentjs.com/
* http://www.datejs.com/
* https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+date+library most will handle date parsing and comparison.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
var year = '2013';
var month = '04';
var day = '18';

var hour = '12';
var min = '35';

var reserv = new Date(year,month,day,hour,min)

console.log(reserv);
```

Those year, month and day values you might want to fetch for yourselves by checking the current date. This is purely to show how to convert the string into a date.

Use `reserv.getTime()` to convert to milliseconds time and thus being able to compare two times;

```
reserv.getTime() - reserv2.getTime()
```

For more information, check the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: The `getTime` method is unnecessary; `reserv - reserv2` will have the same result.

Comment: @Sortofabeginner Fair enough :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use [regular expressions](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_regexp.asp) and the [Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp).

RegExps would be used to extract hours and minutes from the date string,

and the Date object would be used for comparisons.