# how to convert string to valid date in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, string-to-datetime

I have time interval e.g. "01:30:00" as the string. Now I want to convert this string to a valid DateTime in javascript to manipulate. for example: add 1 hour.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072056/convert-string-to-time-javascript-hm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.

**first** Get current DateTime by `new Date()` **second** use `.toDateString()` **third** attach my time interval e.g. "01:30:00".

```
new Date().toDateString() + ' ' + "01:30:00" // Mon May 09 2016 01:30:00
```

Now use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```
var t = moment(new Date().toDateString() + ' ' + "01:30:00");
```

**ّFinaly** add for example 1 hour by [moment().add()](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/)

```
var finalTime = t.add(60, 'minutes').format("hh:mm");
```

**demo**

```js
var stringTimeInterval = "01:30:00";

   var t = moment(new Date().toDateString() + ' ' + stringTimeInterval);

   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = t.add(60, 'minutes').format("hh:mm:00");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the momentjs library to do this rather easily.

```
var epoch = moment(str).unix();
```

http://momentjs.com/

Also refer

http://www.sitepoint.com/beginners-guide-to-javascript-date-and-time/

Comment: returned value is NaN