# comparing current time with input time in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, time, compare

From the following html and javascript code i hope to compare the input time with current time! If the input time is less than 2 hours i want to print "Less time" in the label and if its more than 2 hours i want to print "sufficient time" in the label!

```js
 
    function test(){
     var element = document.getElementById("time").value;
     var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getTime();
     if(element-n>2){
       document.getElementById("check").innerHTML="sufficient time";
     }
     else{
      document.getElementById("check").innerHTML="Less time";
     
     }
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    
    <body>
     <form>
      <span>Time</span>
     <input type="time" id="time">
      
        <input type="button" value="CHECK"   onclick="test();"> <br>
      <label id="check"></label>
              <input class="button" type=reset name=reset value=Cancel>
     </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

when i evaluate this i always get less time! How can i correct mycode?

Comment: The input value is a string of format `hh:mm:ss.ms`, so you cannot perform arithmetic operations directly. You'll have to parse it first.

Comment: i have no idea about the way to handle it :(

Comment: [This SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18623783/2581562) will help you.
You have to use moment.js, don't bother with an individual solution, it can get very tricky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Working example of your code**

```js
function test() {

  var element = document.getElementById("time").value;
  
  if (element == "") {
  alert("Please Enter Time");
    return false;  
  }
  else {
  
  // get system local time
  var d = new Date();
  var m = d.getMinutes();
  var h = d.getHours();
  if(h == '0') {h = 24}
  
  var currentTime = h+"."+m;
  console.log(currentTime);
 
  // get input time
  var time = element.split(":");
  var hour = time[0];
  if(hour == '00') {hour = 24}
  var min = time[1];
  
  var inputTime = hour+"."+min;
  console.log(inputTime);
  
  var totalTime = currentTime - inputTime;
  console.log(totalTime);
  
  if ((Math.abs(totalTime)) > 2) {
    document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = "sufficient time";
  } 
  else {
    document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = "Less time";

  }
    }
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <form>
    <span>Time</span>
    <input type="time" id="time" required>

    <input type="button" value="CHECK" onclick="return test();">
    <br>
    <label id="check"></label>
    <input class="button" type=reset name=reset value=Cancel>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanx alot! what does this " if(hour == '00') {hour = 24}" do?

Comment: @SachiniKarunaratne just to remove any conflict between hours. Example if  it is 12:00 AM you'll get 00 as a hour so.

Answer (score 1):

You are not considering that input value in your field has to be *parsed* to a Date value to be of any use in calculation:

```
function test(){
    var timeNow = new Date();
    var tm = document.getElementById("time");
    var timeParts = tm.split(":");
    var inputTime = new Date(timeNow.getYear() , timeNow.getMonth() ,     timeNow.getDate() , parseInt(timeParts[0]), parseInt(timeParts[1]), 0, 0);

    var diff = Math.abs(timeNow.getTime() - inputTime.getTime());

    if( diff > 2*60*60*1000 ) 
        document.getElementById("check").innerHTML="sufficient  time";
    else
        document.getElementById("check").innerHTML="Less time";
     }
```

I am assuming you are checking for two hours before or after the current time. If not, feel free to remove the Math.abs and use accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a type mismatch. You are comparing a timestamp to a time string. The `getTime()` returns a timestamp that specifies a time on a particular date, whereas the time string is just a string such as `02:02` which doesn't specify a date.

You will need to collect date and time from inputs, then construct a `Date` object from the input, then compare two `getTime()` results. That way you will be comparing two timestamps.

It is important that the input includes the date because of what happens around midnight. If the current time is 23:30 and the input time is 01:15, how will your code know whether the user meant 1:15 tomorrow morning?

Answer (score 0):

getTime() returns milliseconds, so to get two hours, simply multiply 1000 * 60 * 60 to get one hour in milliseconds.

element will contain a string, like "12:30" and must be converted, this one might help you further:

[Convert string to time JavaScript (h:m)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072056/convert-string-to-time-javascript-hm)

Hope it helps.