# convert only time String to Timestamp

Tags: javascript, timestamp

So what I have is a time string which shows the time as `h:m:s.ms`
But the problem is that I want to covert them to timestamp values it shows `NaN` values.

I am using `Date.parse()` to convert the time into timestamp.

Here is the code that I have tried.

```
var date;
function myFunction() {
  var d = new Date();
  var h = addZero(d.getHours(), 2);
  var m = addZero(d.getMinutes(), 2);
  var s = addZero(d.getSeconds(), 2);
  var ms = addZero(d.getMilliseconds(), 3);
  var maindate = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + "." + ms ;
  var datestring = Date.parse(maindate)
  var data = Math.random(0,1); 
  console.log("Date : ", maindate) ;
  console.log("Data : ", data);
 }
  myFunction();
```

You can see the `date` and `data` in the console window.

the `date` variable here shows NaN Value.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What's in your `addZero` function

Comment: Similar question in this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16072056/convert-string-to-time-javascript-hm

Comment: Check out moment.js (https://momentjs.com/) library. It handles dates easily

Comment: `Date.parse(maindate)` returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC. What do you expect it to return by giving it hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds? The number of milliseconds since Jan 1 1970?

Comment: `return by giving it hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds?`

exactly @BrettGregson

Comment: What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: the output to be in `timestamp` value of `h:m:s.ms` like `1379426880000` @BrettGregson

Comment: If you want a timestamp, you need a full date with day month and year

Comment: Yes I got it. I got the solution I'll answer it right away

Comment: Please edit your question and change the typo `Data.parse()` to `Date.parse()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing dates is a pain in JavaScript as there's no extensive native support. However you could do something like the following by relying on the Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond]) constructor signature of the Date object.

```
var dateString = '17-09-2013 10:08',
    dateTimeParts = dateString.split(' '),
    timeParts = dateTimeParts[1].split(':'),
    dateParts = dateTimeParts[0].split('-'),
    date;

date = new Date(dateParts[2], parseInt(dateParts[1], 10) - 1, dateParts[0], timeParts[0], timeParts[1]);

console.log(date.getTime()); //1379426880000
console.log(date); //Tue Sep 17 2013 10:08:00 GMT-0400
```

You could also use a regular expression with capturing groups to parse the date string in one line.

```
var dateParts = '17-09-2013 10:08'.match(/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+) (\d+):(\d+)/);

console.log(dateParts); // ["17-09-2013 10:08", "17", "09", "2013", "10", "08"]
```

Comment: can you please update your answer for having miliseconds data also. I am not able to configure that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a timestamp you need a full time with day, month and year

```js
var date;

function myFunction() {
  var d = new Date();
  var h = addZero(d.getHours(), 2);
  var m = addZero(d.getMinutes(), 2);
  var s = addZero(d.getSeconds(), 2);
  var ms = addZero(d.getMilliseconds(), 3);

  var day = d.getDate();
  var month = d.getMonth() + 1; // getMonth returns an integer between 0 and 11
  var year = d.getFullYear();  

  var maindate = `${day}-${month}-${year} ${h}:${m}:${s}.${ms}`;
  var datestring = Date.parse(maindate)
  console.log("Data : ", datestring);
 }
  myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

As I want to get the `timestamp` in result. I got my sholution of the above question that I posted

Here is the Final code which is giving me the expected result.

```
  function addZero(x,n) {
  while (x.toString().length < n) {
    x = "0" + x;
  }
  return x;
}

var date;
function myFunction() {
  var d = new Date();
  var day = d.getDate();
  var month = d.getMonth() + 1; // Since getMonth() returns month from 0-11 not 1-12
  var year = d.getFullYear();
  var h = addZero(d.getHours(), 2);
  var m = addZero(d.getMinutes(), 2);
  var s = addZero(d.getSeconds(), 2);
  var ms = addZero(d.getMilliseconds(), 3);
  var maindate = year +"-" + day + "-" + month +" "+ h + ":" + m + ":" + s + "." + ms ;
   var datestring = Date.parse(maindate)
  var data = Math.random(0,1); 
  console.log("Date : ", datestring) ;
  console.log("Data : ", data);
 }

    myFunction();
```

I had to include the day month and year value also. WHich I updated in the Answer. rest of the code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you don't need your `addZero()` function any more and it's unnecessary to delacre `var date;` globally.

```js
var d = new Date();
var h = d.getHours();
var m = d.getMinutes();
var s = d.getSeconds();
var ms = d.getMilliseconds();
var day = d.getDate();
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
var year = d.getFullYear();  

var maindate = day + '-' + month + '-' + year + ' ' + h + ':' + m + ':' + s + '.' + ms;
var datestring = Date.parse(maindate);

console.log("Data : ", datestring);
```

Take a look at [momentjs.com](https://momentjs.com/), maybe this could be a clean and simple solution for you too - depending on your environment.

Answer (score 0):

One way to parse only time in string format to date date object is as shown here.

```
var time = "14:43:30";

var date = new Date();
date.setHours(time.substring(0,2));
date.setMinutes(time.substring(3,5));
date.setSeconds(time.substring(6,8));
console.log(date);
```

Then you can convert it to timestamp like this.

```
var timestamp = date.getTime();
```

Here you can give time in string format and convert it into date.

In momentjs you can convert is as follows

```
var timestamp = moment(time, "HH:mm:ss").unix();
```